# SharePoint 2013 Office web apps preview not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office-web-app

I am having issues with the preview of our sharepoint office documents, it is not working, i have checked the OWA Server and the owa services are running . I also checked the binding using Get-SPWOPIBinding and it returned the bindings to the owa server. I have also set the zone to external-https using

```
Set-SPWOPIZone –zone “external-https”
```

because i saw that the zone was binded to external-https in my sharepoint servers. but still the issue is still there.not sure why and I don't understand the ULS logs either. these are the ULS logs for the correlation id of one of the documents i was trying to preview.

> Unexpected Exception in
>   SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory for usage
>   'DistributedLogonTokenCache' - Exception 'System.ArgumentException:
>   Max connections value should be in the range 1 to 100.  Parameter
>   name: value      at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactoryConfiguration.set_MaxConnectionsToServer(Int32
>   value)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()'.
>
> Token Cache: Failed to initialize SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache 
>   Exception: 'System.ArgumentException: Max connections value should be
>   in the range 1 to 100.  Parameter name: value      at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactoryConfiguration.set_MaxConnectionsToServer(Int32
>   value)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCache..ctor(String
>   name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType
>   containerType, Boolean encryptData)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache..ctor(String
>   name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType
>   containerType, Boolean encrptyData, TimeSpan
>   minimumTokenExpirationWindow)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCacheInitializer.Init(Object
>   state)'.

i'm stuck and i need assistance

Answer (score 0):

Also check in Event Viewer and see if you can get an error code(s).  Looks like AppFabric (Distributed Cache) is having an issue, but it may be a symptom of something else, sometimes only one of several issues.  There is a fine tuning script available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/manage-the-distributed-cache-service#finetune), but make sure you know what you're doing.  Try setting the Max Connections to 1, test it, and then bump it up to 10 and see if you have any issues.  Might want to do this during a maintenance window as a restart may be required.

Comment: HI @sparch found a new error: SPShareByLinkHandler.Initialize : Not a ShareByLink request - missing access token